# C# Socket Listener (Server)

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, stream, listener

I have the below program that receives socket streams in form of XML and inserts them into SQL database. My problem is the following:
 - When the program is launched in debug mode, all the xml streams are inserted successfully into the database.
 - When it is launched normally (no debug mode), the program will insert one xml stream and miss the other (So if I had 20 streams, only 10 will be inserted).

What could be the error in this code?

```
client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                    netstream = client.GetStream();
                    Status = "Connected to a client\n";   
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize + 1];
                        netstream.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(client.ReceiveBufferSize));
                        // Return the data received from the client 
                        string clientdata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
                        Status="Client sent: " + clientdata ;
                        StorePolicy(clientdata);
                        Query = clientdata;
                        Query = Query.Replace("\0", "");
                        StorePolicy(Query);

                        Status="Received Query: " + Query;
                        StorePolicy("Received Query: " + Query);
                        netstream.Close();
                        client.Close();  
                        ///////////////insert into database/////////    
                       try
                         {                               
                           SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                           SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand();     
                           string[] words = Query.Split(new[] { "</RECORD>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);    
                           StorePolicy(Query);
                           foreach (string word in words)
                           {
                               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
                               {

                                    record = word.Replace("'", "''") + "</RECORD>";
                                    StorePolicy(record);
                                   StrQuery = "INSERT INTO SMSListenner(XMLText) VALUES ('" + record.Replace("'", "''") + "')";
                                   Cmd = new SqlCommand(StrQuery, conn);
                                   conn.Open();
                                   Cmd.ExecuteReader();
                                   conn.Close();    
                                   StorePolicy(StrQuery);

                               }
                           }    
                         }
```

Comment: [mcve] please.  This is too much code.  Start deleting stuff until you have the least amount of code that still has the issue.

Comment: @rory.ap done. please check. thanks

Comment: Code should be well formatted, almost "compile ready" this is not what it is. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and come back.

Comment: You're making socket programming mistake number one, namely ignoring the return value of `netstream.Read()`.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN clearly says:

> The TcpListener class provides simple methods that listen for and
>   accept incoming connection requests **in blocking synchronous mode**.

This means once one client is connected, it blocks every other client until your "poor man web server" finished with the stream. Other clients that wait in the queue might timeout in mean time. Mind yourself that you are doing a hell of a lot to process request. This means that you will block other clients for a significant amount of time.

Also, you have no exception handling, so one client can kill your entire "server".

My advice, if it's not a student's project to learn how sockets work, use proper web server with isolation between connections, and capable of processing multiple connections at the same time.